# Does some boost::asio async function connect a handler to an operation so that the handler is triggered once?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Let us say we have a handler `H` and an acceptor `A`. And let's say that we do `A.async_accept(some_slave_socket, H)`. Then somebody wants to connect so `H` has been called. It has been executed. Then somebody else wants to connect. Has `H` been called for the second time or had we had to call `async_accept` again for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler will be called only once. Otherwise it would corrupt your socket as it uses a reference to that socket. What you can do though, is calling the `async_accept` within your handler to start a new cycle:

```
tcp::acceptor acceptor;

void accept_handler(const asio::error_code& error, asio::ip::tcp::socket peer)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        my_connection_container.push_back(std::move(peer));
    }

    acceptor.async_accept(accept_handler);
}

int main()
{
    acceptor = tcp:acceptor(my_io_context);
    acceptor.async_accept(accept_handler);
    // ...
}
```